Central Limit Theorem and Gaussian Information Bottleneck
I have a question, maybe stupid, but I can't find an answer.
We know that the Gaussian Information Bottleneck solution exists in closed form, and it is invariant to any linear and invertible transformation of the data. Let us consider the situation where we have $(X,Y)$ such that $Y=AX+\epsilon$ and $X$ is non-gaussian distributed, but its data distribution verifies al the hypotheses of the Central Limit Theorem. Thus, $\tilde{X}=\boldsymbol{B}X$ should be approximately Gaussian distributed and $\tilde{Y}=A\tilde{X}+\tilde{\epsilon}$ is Gaussian too (since it is a linear transformation of Gaussian variable), and the Gaussian Information Bottleneck should be optimal, but the solution of the GIB should be remain the same under the linear transformation. So, how is it possible that the GIB solution is optimal in one case but not in the other one, if the solution is invariant to linear transformations?
